# How to Pickle / deepcopy Python class created with maturin?

Tags: python, rust, deep-copy, pyo3, maturin

I've been working on integrating rust code into python using PyO3 and Maturin. I've successfully written my Rust class and gotten most of the functionality to work, however I haven't been able to successfully deepcopy the object. I've tried workarounds using wrapper classes and custom defined **deepcopy** and **getattr**/**setattr** to not much avail, since it seems that the rust functions aren't pickleable. The Rust class is included in a standard #[pymodule], and tagged as a standard #[pyclass]. Has anyone encountered this issue before, and is there any way around it? Or should I just avoid deepcopying in my python code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `__deepcopy__()` method, like:

```rust
fn __deepcopy__(&self, _memo: &PyDict) -> Self {
    self.clone()
}
```

[As explained in the `copy` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Pickling is more involved, but see [PyO3 issue #100](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/issues/100).